# Selenium find iframe inside second tr that table as another tr that contains specific text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Not sure if the title is clear.

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Text to Find</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <iframe></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I have several of this blocks inside the application I am testing (this is simplified)

I want to get the iframe that is inside the "Text to Find" that this changes on each table that contains the iframe.

Is it possible? I have try something like this but isn't working:

```
//table[contains(.,'Text to Find')]/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hard coding the row number in the x-path `//table[contains(.,'Text to Find')]/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe`.

Your can try the following x-path.

```
//table/tbody/tr/td/div[contains(.,'Text to Find')]//iframe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below xPath

```
//div[contains(Text(), 'Text to Find')]/../../following-sibling::tr/td/iframe
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was before this code. this is working as expected.

thank you for the replys

Comment: Please use comments for meta commentary, this helps keep the answer section relevant :)